# Update a join tables using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my select query

```
select s.enabled,
       s.totalpoints,
       transaction_diff_dates
from loyalty_scheme l
  join subscribe_merchant s on (l.scheme_id = s.schemerefid)
  join transaction t on (s.unipoint_customer_ref_id = t.unipoint_customer_ref_id)
where (s.transaction_diff_dates = to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
  and (s.merchant_ref_id = 11)
  and (s.schemerefid = (select scheme_id
                        from loyalty_scheme
                        where (minimum_purchase_amount = (select min(minimum_purchase_amount)
                                                          from loyalty_scheme
                                                          where merchant_id = 11))
                        group by scheme_id))
group by s.unipoint_customer_ref_id,
         s.enabled,
         s.totalpoints,
         s.transaction_diff_dates
```

This query returns two rows.

I need to update this enabled filed = 'false' , and totalPoint = 0 filed , instead  of selecting

So I tried to write an update query

```
UPDATE subscribe_merchant 
SET enabled = 'true'  
FROM loyalty_scheme L 
JOIN subscribe_merchant S ON (L.scheme_id = S.schemerefid)
JOIN transaction T ON (S.unipoint_customer_ref_id = T.unipoint_customer_ref_id) 
WHERE (s.transaction_diff_dates = to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
  AND (s.merchant_ref_id = 11) 
  AND (s.schemerefid = (SELECT scheme_id   
                        FROM loyalty_scheme 
                        WHERE (minimum_purchase_amount = (SELECT MIN(minimum_purchase_amount) 
                                                          FROM loyalty_scheme 
                                                          WHERE merchant_id = 11))
                        GROUP BY scheme_id))
GROUP BY 
    s.unipoint_customer_ref_id, s.enabled, 
    s.totalpoints, s.transaction_diff_dates
```

but this update query dose not work.

Please help me to write the update query

Comment: These queries are hideous, and to make matters worse, it looks like you're using Oracle (you never told us), which doesn't support update joins.  You should add more information to your question if you want help.

Comment: sorry for that,  im using postgres

Comment: here where condition did not check in the update query, with and without where condition update same number of rows

Comment: Looks like you want something like a `update ... where exists (...)` not a join

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you storing dates as varchar?